# writeRaster to NETCDF parallelisation R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, maps, time-series, raster

I have a large `rasterstack (s)` with the following details:

```
class       : RasterStack
dimensions  : 510, 1068, 544680, 19358  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent      : -141, -52, 41, 83.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
names       : Jan.1961.1, Jan.1961.2, Jan.1961.3, Jan.1961.4, Jan.1961.5, Jan.1961.6, Jan.1961.7, Jan.1961.8, Jan.1961.9, Jan.1961.10, Jan.1961.11, Jan.1961.12, Jan.1961.13, Jan.1961.14, Jan.1961.15, ...
time        : 1961-01-01 - 2013-12-31 (range)
```

Doing something like:

```
writeRaster( s,"PP", overwrite=TRUE, format="CDF", varname="P", varunit="mm", 
             longname="totals", xname="lon", yname="lat",zname="time",
             zunit="numeric")
```

takes more than 2 weeks to complete on my computer. How can I run this in parallel (may be via `foreach loop and %dopar% command`) to get the same results with shorter processing time?

**sample data**

```
s=brick(nrows=510, ncols=1068, xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84", nl=193581)
dates=seq(as.Date("1961-01-01"), as.Date("2013-12-31"), by="day")
s<- setZ(s,dates)
```

NB: my true data is a rasterstack not brick.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with netcdf files, but running your "sample data" script then your writeRaster() script gives an error because it says all values are NA.  Using setValues() to set all values to 1 (for example), also throws an error: "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 78.6 Gb".  With a size that large on a regular laptop I'm not sure how much parallelization will speed it up.

Comment: @ken thanks for adding values to the sample data. I encountered the same error when running my actual data. I thought parallel computing might help.

Comment: You can maybe save your layers in separate netcdf files, using `writeRaster` in parallel for the different layers. Then, if you're working on Linux, you can use package `nco` in the terminal (or from R with `system` and some `paste` for the names) with the function `ncecat`. I have no idea if this will be faster, but this is an alternative for parallel writing as you asked...

Comment: @StatnMap I would appreciate if you show me how to unstack and write each layer seperately to netcdf. Sure, I can use `mergetime` in `CDO` or `*cat` to put the netcdfs together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code, but I did not really tested it on a big dataset. And I did not tested the `ncecat` part... I'll update it later, but you can try in the meantime.

```
wd <- "~/Bureau/Tmp"

# stack with 16 layers
nl <- 16 # 19358
s <- brick(nrows = 510,  ncols = 1068,
           xmn = -180, xmx = 180, ymn = -90, ymx = 90,
           crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84",
           nl = nl)
dates <- seq(as.Date("1961-01-01"), as.Date("2013-12-31"), by = "day")
s <- setZ(s, dates)

require(foreach)
require(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)

tmp <- foreach(i = 1:nlayers(s)) %dopar% 
{  
  r <- raster::raster(s, i)
  raster::writeRaster(r, 
                      filename = paste0(wd,
                        "/PP_", formatC(i, width = 6, flag = "0")),
                      overwrite=TRUE, format="CDF", varname="P", varunit="mm", 
               longname="totals", xname="lon", yname="lat",zname="time",
               zunit="numeric")
  rm(r)
}
stopCluster(cl)    

ppfiles <- list.files(wd)[grep("PP_", list.files(wd))]
system(paste0("ncecat ppfiles output.nc")
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It works well for me. May be you could include `stopCluster(cl)` at the end of the code.